# What is a root element in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have written a directive like this:

```
app.directive('headersort', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            sortBy: '=',
            title: '='
        },
        template: '<th>{{ title }}</th>',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) { 
            scope.sortBy = attributes.sortBy;
            scope.title = attributes.title;

        }
    };
});
```

And I use it like this:

```
<headersort sortBy="Name" title="Product">
```

What I want is that `<headersort sortBy="Name" title="Product">` is replaced with `<th>Product</th>`. But I get an error saying:

`Template must have exactly one root element. was: <th>{{ title }}</th>`

But I do have one root element, right? My root element is `<th>`, so why is angular throwing this error? What are the conditions/definition of a root element?

Comment: Also, all the code in your link function is not required, that why you have the scope declaration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459) issue.

Try changing your directive from `restrict: 'E'` to `restrict: 'A'` and change your HTML to `<th headersort sortBy="Name" title="Product"></th>`

Comment: Thanks. The link to the issues is indeed my problem. I'm solving it now as an attribute, instead of a table header.

Answer (score 0):

I think its saying about the `table` element. Did you define it somewhere?